# How to set the 'terminal png size' to '2.5in' (IEEEtran) in gnuplot?

Tags: latex, gnuplot, ieee

I set the image size as `1024*768` in gnuplot.

```
set terminal png size 1024,768
```

In order to put it in IEEEtran latex, I have to scale down.

```
\begin{figure}[!t]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{myfigure}
\caption{Simulation Results}
\label{fig_sim}
\end{figure}
```

However, the font size is quite small.

BTW, the format of figures for **IEEEtran** is: `\includegraphics[width=2.5in]{myfigure}`.

---

@Christoph I generate the figure using `set terminal pdfcairo size 2.5in,2.5in font ',8'` as you mentioned. However, the figure is very ugly.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "appropriate"?

Comment: @Werner, I set the image size as `1027 * 768` in gnuplot and insert it into latex with `\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{figure}`. It looks ugly.

Comment: @Werner Sorry for not expressing myself clearly. I have edited my question.

Comment: Please undo your last edit, since you posted this as new question, which is the right way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a pixel graphic for a publication, but rather a vector format like pdf!

There you just give the physical size which your final image should have. Then you don't need to scale the image and it will appear exactly like you prepared it:

```
set terminal pdfcairo size 2.5in,1.875in font ',8'
```

And then include it with

```
\includegraphics{myfigure}
```

Maybe you must tweak the margins a little bit to use as much of the space as possible.

Comment: Awesome.Why is the height `1.875in`? Is it standard?

Comment: No, that is `768.0/1024 * 2.5`, but basically, selecting the aspect ratio is up to you

Comment: The figure is very ugly using `set terminal pdfcairo size 2.5in,2.5in font ',8'`, pls see the edited question.